# Cross compiler include std lib

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm on debian and have compiled gcc 5.3.x as a cross compiler. My kernel project has successfully built and runs on qemu. This was done by following the [OS Dev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones) article on getting started with os development.

The question that I cannot find a good answer for is about linking to the a standard c library.

Can I compile my cross compiler to include the standard lib (stdint.h, string.h, etc.) linked at compilation time?

It is my understanding that these headers are platform independent so having them included would not be bad thing. Am I wrong in thinking that this would be okay?

Comment: No, there's no way. It's impossible to implement things such as `stdio.h` in kernel mode. They require support from an operating system, but you're *in* the operating system, so you can't do that! However, you can write a modified library yourself that excludes all the unavailable stuff, such as `stdio`. However, if you're talking about porting a usermode standard C library, then you'ld have to write one yourself from scratch, because of the kernel-specific [system call interface](http://wiki.osdev.org/System_Calls).

Comment: BTW, the API exposed by the headers is platform independent. However, the *internals* of both the headers and the library sources definitively are not. For instance, how would you describe `stdio.h`'s `FILE` in a portable way?

Comment: Oh, okay. Your second comment made everything click. Initially I was worried about linking my host libraries to the cross compiler but then I got greedy thinking I could share stdio. I appreciate your comments.